Hartshorne Chapter II Exercise 3.22d)
Can someone give me a hint for Hartshorne Chapter II Exercise 3.22d) part 3? The question is:

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a dominant morphism of integral schemes of finite type over a field $k$.

Let $Y'$ be a closed irreducible subset of $Y$, whose generic point $\eta'$ is contained in $f(X)$. Let $Z$ be any irreducible component of $f^{-1}(Y') $, such that $\eta' \in f(Z)$, and show that $\codim(Z,X) \le \codim(Y',Y)$.
Let $e = \dim X - \dim Y$ be the \textit{relative dimension} of $X$ over $Y$. For any point $y \in f(X)$, show that every irreducible component of the fibre $X_y$ has dimension $\ge e$.
[Hint: Let $Y' = \overline{\{y\}  }$, and use (a) and (Ex. 3.20b).]
Show that there is a dense open subset $U \subseteq X$, such that for any $y \in f(U)$, $\dim U_y = e$.
\ifhint
[Hint: First reduce to the case where $X$ and $Y$ are affine, say $X = \Spec A$ and $Y = \Spec B$. Then $A$ is a finitely generated $B$-algebra. Take $t_{1},\ldots,t_e\in A$ which form a transcendence base of $K(X)$ over $K(Y)$, and let $X_1 = \Spec B[t_{1},\ldots,t_e]$. Then $X_{1} $ is isomorphic to affine $e$-space over $Y$, and the morphism $X \to X_1$ is generically finite. Now use (Ex. 3.7) above.]
\fi
Going back to our original morphism $f: X \to Y$, for any integer $h$, let $E_h$ be the set of points $x \in X$ such that, letting $y = f(x)$, there is an irreducible component $Z$ of the fibre $X_y$, containing $x$, and having $\dim Z \ge h$. Show that (1) $E_e = X$ (use (b) above); (2) if $h > e$, then $E_h$ is not dense in $X$ (use (c) above); and (3) $E_h$ is closed, for all $h$ (use induction on $\dim X$).
Prove the following theorem of Chevalley-see Cartan and Chevalley [1, expose 8]. For each integer $h$, let $C_h$ be the set of points $y \in Y$ such that $\dim X_y = h$. Then the subsets $C_h$ are constructible, and $C_e$ contains an open dense subset of $Y$.


I don't understand how we can use the hint of "induct on the dim X". What subschemes can we consider that help us understand $E_h$?
I have tried thinking about how to remove certain irreducible sets to drop the dimension but I either can't seem to relate it to $E_h$ or do it in a way that helps understand $E_h$.
Thanks!

Can you put the exercise in the question, so people who don't have access to the book can read it.

@DavidLui I have added it.

You are still omitting relevant information. What's $E_n$? What are the two previous parts of the problem referenced here? Leaving this information out decreases the chance that others will answer your question (they'll have to go and get the book unless they perfectly remember all the parts of the question) and increases the chance your question will be closed (you're on 3 votes to close right now).

$E_h$ for $h>e$ is contained in the complement of the dense open subset $U$ from part (c) of the exercise, and it is closed there by induction.

@KReiser Sorry, I have added the whole question now.

@danneks Why is $\dim X \setminus U < \dim X$?

@Vincent Tran: take a maximal chain of irreducible closed subsets of $X\ \backslash\ U$. These subsets are also closed and irreducible in $X$, and we can add $X$ itself to this chain, so that its length increases.
